# Nested vs. conditional logit regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, modeling, conditional-probability

I am trying to estimate a logit regression model with travel mode choice (categorical) being the dependent variable; explanatory variables include age (categorical), income (categorical), gender (binary), and travel cost (continuous). I also have information on origin town (6 digit code for each town, about 50 towns) of the travellers, which I want to control for in the logit model. I am using R.

I saw some other posts on StackOverflow saying that similar problems could be solved using a nested logit (origin town as the nest). While some of my research suggested a conditional logit could be an option. Could you guys advise on what the key differences are between nested and conditional logit in solving my problem in this case?

Comment: Are you sure they were not talking about rute choice and not mode choice. Anyway it is my understanding that the nested logit allows the researcher to nest alternatives and I dont see any way to nest modes according to town of origin.